# ExtJS - Open tab through clicking on link in GridPanel (column renderer)

Tags: hyperlink, extjs, grid, listener, renderer

I created link in the grid panel, so that when I click on the link and it will open another tab in the tab panel. Currently I render the column cell output into html href with ***onClick*** event. But it seems that got error when the renderer method **openrender()** call the other method **newtab()**, which showing error function **newtab()** cannot be found. It maybe because of the ***onClick*** event can only call to methods/functions outside **"Ext.onReady(function(){"** block? Does anyone know solution for this, any help is much appreciated thanks.

Or if you have other ways to achieve the same purpose also feel free to share. Thanks.

```
function newtab(state,ptt,status){
    tabs.add({
        title: 'Order List Detail',
                iconCls: 'tabs',
                items: [
                new Ext.Panel({
                    height: 40,
                    html: 'some html'
                })
                ,layout: 'fit'
        }).show();

}

function openrender(value, p, record){
    return String.format('<a <href="#" onClick="newtab(\'{1}\',\'{2}\',\'{3}\')">{0}</a></b>',value, record.data.state, record.data.ptt, 'Open');
}

var grid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
frame:true,
title: 'Pending Orders',
layout: 'fit',
store: catstore,
stripeRows: true,
loadMask: true,
iconCls: 'grid',
tbar: [{
        text: 'Category',
        xtype: 'label'
    }
],
columns: [
{header: "State Name", dataIndex: 'state', sortable: true},
{header: "PTT Name", dataIndex: 'ptt', sortable: true},
{header: "Open", dataIndex: 'openstatus', sortable: true, renderer: openrender}
]
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well I just found out another workaround by using grid cellclick listener

var grid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
frame:true,
title: 'Pending Orders',
layout: 'fit',
store: catstore,
stripeRows: true,
loadMask: true,
iconCls: 'grid',
tbar: [{
        text: 'Category',
  xtype: 'label'
    }
],
columns: [
{header: "State Name", dataIndex: 'state', sortable: true},
{header: "PTT Name", dataIndex: 'ptt', sortable: true},
{header: "Open", dataIndex: 'openstatus', sortable: true, renderer: openrender}
],
listeners:{
 cellclick: function(grid, rowIndex, columnIndex) {
  // Get the Record for the row
        var record = grid.getStore().getAt(rowIndex);
        // Get field name for the column
        var fieldName = grid.getColumnModel().getDataIndex(columnIndex);

if(fieldName == 'openstatus')
   newtab(record.data.state, record.data.ptt, 'Open');
 }
}
});